# Encontrar el Uid del firebase/autentication para eliminar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic

hola buenas a todos/as quisiera que me ayudasen a encontrar una solucion o una variante a la problematica que tengo. el problema es el siguiente:
tengo un proyecto en angular ionic, la cual quiero realizar un gestor de usuarios y actualmente tengo lo que seria el registro de ususarios y listado de estos, pero al momento de realizar el eliminar usuario del firebase, no me deja eliminar porque en la consola me dice que no se a encontrado el usuario por el UID de este, pero he estado analizando el codigo que segun yo esta bien y no se me ocurre otra solucion aqui le dejo la informacion de los codigos

authService (servicio para gestion de las cuentas):

```
**import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Empleado, Usuario } from './modelUser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  async registrar(usuario: Usuario) {
    try {
      const credential = await this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usuario.correo, usuario.password);
      const uid = credential.user?.uid;
      if (uid) {
        await this.firestore.collection('Usuarios').doc(uid).set(usuario);
      } else {
        throw new Error('No se pudo obtener el UID del usuario.');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error('Error al registrar usuario: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  async registrarByAdmin(empleado: Empleado) {
    try {
      const credential = await this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(empleado.correo, empleado.password);
      const uid = credential.user?.uid;
      if (uid) {
        await this.firestore.collection('Empleados').doc(uid).set(empleado);
      } else {
        throw new Error('No se pudo obtener el UID del empleado.');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error('Error al registrar empleado: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  async getEmpleados(): Promise<Empleado[]> {
    try {
      const snapshot = await this.firestore.collection('Empleados').get().toPromise();
      if (snapshot) {
        return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data() as Empleado);
      } else {
        throw new Error('No se encontraron documentos en la colección Empleados.');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error('Error al obtener la lista de empleados: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  async ingresar(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      this.router.navigate(['/perfil']);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Error al iniciar sesión:', error);
      throw new Error('Error al iniciar sesión: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  async cerrarSesion() {
    try {
      await this.afAuth.signOut();
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Error al cerrar sesión:', error);
      throw new Error('Error al cerrar sesión: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  
  modificarUsuario() {
  }
  async eliminarUsuario(uid: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const user = await this.afAuth.currentUser;
      if (user) {
        await user.delete();
      } else {
        throw new Error('No se encontró el usuario para eliminar.');
      }
      await this.firestore.collection('Usuarios').doc(uid).delete();
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Error al eliminar usuario:', error);
      throw new Error('Error al eliminar usuario: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  
  
  async getUid(){
    const user = await this.afAuth.currentUser;
    if (user === null){
      return null;
    } else {
      return user?.uid;
    }
  }
  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.afAuth.currentUser.then(user => {
      if (user !== null) {
        return user;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error al obtener el usuario actual:', error);
      throw new Error('Error al obtener el usuario actual: ' + error.message);
    });
  }
  // selecciona al usuario unico
  async getUsuarioID(uid: string): Promise<Usuario> {
    try {
      const docRef = this.firestore.collection('Usuarios').doc(uid);
      const doc = await docRef.get().toPromise();
      if (doc && doc.exists) {
        return doc.data() as Usuario;
      } else {
        throw new Error('No se encontró la información del usuario.');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error('Error al obtener la información del usuario: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  // muestra a todos los usuarios en una lista
  async getUsuarios(): Promise<Usuario[]> {
    try {
      const snapshot = await this.firestore.collection('Usuarios').get().toPromise();
      if (snapshot) {
        return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data() as Usuario);
      } else {
        throw new Error('No se encontraron documentos en la colección Usuarios.');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error('Error al obtener la lista de usuarios: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
  
  stateAuth(){
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  } 
}**
```

codigo del gestor de usuario y funcion de listado y eliminacion del usuario:

**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/models-srvcs/auth.service';
import { CacheService } from 'src/app/models-srvcs/cache.service';
import { Usuario } from 'src/app/models-srvcs/modelUser';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gestioncli',
  templateUrl: './gestioncli.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gestioncli.component.scss'],
})
export class GestioncliComponent implements OnInit {
  usuarios: Usuario[] = [];
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private toastController: ToastController,
    private router: Router,
    private cacheService: CacheService
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsuarios();
  }
  navigateToPage(page: string) {
    this.router.navigate([page]);
  }
  async getUsuarios() {
    try {
      this.usuarios = this.cacheService.getUsuarios();
      if (this.usuarios.length === 0) {
        this.usuarios = await this.authService.getUsuarios();
        this.cacheService.setUsuarios(this.usuarios);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al obtener usuarios:', error);
    }
  }
  async eliminarCli(uid: string) {
    try {
      await this.authService.eliminarUsuario(uid);
      await this.mostrarMensaje('Cliente eliminado exitosamente.');
      await this.getUsuarios();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al eliminar cliente:', error);
      await this.mostrarMensaje('Error al eliminar cliente.');
    }
  }
  modificarCli(){
    
  }
  async mostrarMensaje(mensaje: string) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: mensaje,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'top',
    });
    toast.present();
  }
}
```

**

aquí les dejo la información de la acción de eliminar:
[image: no se encontró usuario para eliminar]

[image: mas cerca]

Comment: Que tal, has intentado verificar que es lo que recibe como parámetro tu función eliminarUsuario?